# Broken LINQ query with ternary expression

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have this query to fetch a list of articles. If an article `IsLocked`, it should only be included in the list if it was created by the logged in admin user:

```
List<Article> articles = await db
    .Articles
    .Where(a => a.IsLocked
        ? a.CreatedBy.Id == LoggedInAdminUserId
        : true)
    .ToListAsync();
```

But as it is now, any logged in admin user can see all locked articles, no matter who created them.

How should I modify my query?

** EDIT **

The query above is a shortened version. Here is the full query:

```
List<Article> dbm = await db.Articles
    .Where(s => 
        (!s.IsLocked || s.CreatedBy.Id == LoggedInAdminUserId) &&
        s.Title.Contains(search) ||
        s.PreTitle.Contains(search) ||
        s.Preamble.Contains(search) ||
        s.MainText.Contains(search) ||
        s.CreatedBy.Member.FirstName.Contains(search) ||
        s.CreatedBy.Member.LastName.Contains(search) ||
        s.EditedBy.Member.FirstName.Contains(search) ||
        s.EditedBy.Member.LastName.Contains(search) ||
        s.FrontPageItem.PublishedBy.Member.FirstName.Contains(search) ||
        s.FrontPageItem.PublishedBy.Member.LastName.Contains(search)
    )
    .Include(f => f.FrontPageItem)
    .Include(e => e.CreatedBy)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.Member)
    .Include(e => e.EditedBy)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.Member)
    .Include(p => p.PublishReadyBy)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.Member)
    .Include(o => o.ArticleOperations)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.DateCreated)
    .ToListAsync();
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so I guess it's quite late, and my eyes are really squinty. Adding a set of () around all of the `.Contains()` did it:

```
.Where(s => 
    (!s.IsLocked || s.CreatedBy.MemberId == AdminUserMemberId) &&
    (s.Title.Contains(search) ||
    s.PreTitle.Contains(search) ||
    s.Preamble.Contains(search) ||
    s.MainText.Contains(search) ||
    s.CreatedBy.Member.FirstName.Contains(search) ||
    s.CreatedBy.Member.LastName.Contains(search) ||
    s.EditedBy.Member.FirstName.Contains(search) ||
    s.EditedBy.Member.LastName.Contains(search) ||
    s.FrontPageItem.PublishedBy.Member.FirstName.Contains(search) ||
    s.FrontPageItem.PublishedBy.Member.LastName.Contains(search))
)
```

Comment: You could probably simplify the boolean expression from a ternary with `!a.IsLocked || a.CreatedBy.Id == LoggedInAdminUserId`, but your logic looks correct. I'm assuming every admin user has a different value for `LoggedInAdminUserId`?

Comment: Rather than using a conditional expression I'd *strongly* recommend using AND and OR to combine expressions.  It's just far more readable to read `!a.IsLocked || a.CreatedBy.ID == LoggedInAdminUserId` than what you have, even if they're semantically the same.

Comment: what is the type of `Id` and `LoggedInAdminUserId` property?

Comment: @JonathonChase I tried replacing the expression with `!s.IsLocked || s.CreatedBy.Id == LoggedInAdminUserId`, but the result was the same. Yes, every admin user has a unique `LoggedInAdminUserId`.

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu `CreatedBy.MemberId` is `int` and `LoggedInAdminUserId` is `int?`. But I get the same result even if I cast to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your full expression the problem is pretty clear with the boolean logic.

```
(!s.IsLocked || s.CreatedBy.Id == LoggedInAdminUserId) &&
s.Title.Contains(search) ||
s.PreTitle.Contains(search) ||
... more
```

You're checking whether the article is unlocked or the user is the creator/admin, and then disregarding that result for the first positive response from all of your `OR` expressions.

The solution is to use parenthesis like so:

```
(!s.IsLocked || s.CreatedBy.Id == LoggedInAdminUserId) &&
(s.Title.Contains(search) ||
s.PreTitle.Contains(search) ||
... more)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your edited question, you have AND/OR Precedence problem. Your AND/OR Logic has problems.

```
false && true || false || true || ....
```

is actually

```
(false && true) || false || true || ...
```

which results with `true`